# UITableView-didSelectRowAtIndexPath Problems when call didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with CustomCell, in my CustomCell I added `UIImage`,`UILabel`...
But, when I selected cell in row 1 and remove `UIImage` on it : `[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TAG_FOR_TOPIMAG]removeFromSuperview];` However, cell at index 7 was changed same cell 1.

Comment: It hard to tell without seeing how you initialize the cell.
In case you are sharing UIView instances, you'd have to know that a UIView can only be part in one view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table view reuses cells (dequeueReusableCell...).
So, the same cell (view) may be used for more than 1 index in the table.
After you change a cell's layout (add/remove/modify subviews) then this cell (view) will appear modified each time it is presented on the screen - even if it represents different index each time.

For example, in your case you probably have maximum of 6 cells visible in the same time on the screen.
Therefore, you have modified some cell (it was displayed for index 1 once you have modified it), after that you have scrolled the table, the cell with index 1 has disappeared from the screen, then the cell with index 7 should be presented (during the scrolling). The table will use the same cell (exactly the same UITableViewCell object) that was used for displaying row with index 1.
But you have removed the image from it...

You have to keep it in mind all the time when you work with tables.
In your case I would suggest you to set the visibility of the image view to hidden and restore it in each `tableView"cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method (NOT inside the `if (cell == nil)` statement - after it).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'm has been change "removeFromSuperview" by "setHidden:YES" . But it not change!

Comment: This is not the only thing that you should do according to my answer. You have to restore its hidden status in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. You should save this hidden/visible state in your data structure and each time before you return a cell from cellForRowAtIndexPath you should set it...